# Installation of pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing

I was working with an old version of Tikz. It appeared I could not use some features, probably because I had an outdated version.

So I tried to reinstall a new version of pgf. I downloaded it and tried as best as possible to get it installed... No result. The instructions are a shame. Even worse: in the process of doing so my old tikz does not even work anymore. It says 'I can't find file pgfutil-common.tex'.

I probably did something wrong.

Can somebody please tell me - in detail and in extremely simple terms - what to do? Even if I now run '\usepackage{Tikz}' it doesn't work.

I have a TexShop. In some map in my library I have a map called 'Tex'. I think I did something wrong by changing things in this map.

---

Sorry for my incomplete information.

- I'm working on a Mac operating system.
- In the map 'TeX' where I believe my tex is installed there is a file called 'TeX Distribution Helper', if I click on it it says 'Choose a system wide TeX distribution'; then I have two options, either gwTeX or TeXLive-2007. So far I've *always* been using the TeXLive-2007 option I believe - until yesterday, for some reason I changed it to gwTeX. I think I perhaps screwed up by changing this to gwTeX (from that moment I think the Tikz package didn't work anymore).

I've now re-set this to 'TeXLive-2007', and the Tikz works again - that is, if I put `\usepackage{tikz}` in my tex-file I do not get error messages, and I can use the "basic" commands in TikZ, they work and without errors. *However*, I still cannot use most of the TikZ libraries and so on (for instance, if I put `\usetikzlibrary{shadows}`, I get the message `'I can't find the file pgflibrarytikzshadows.code.tex'`). Remarkably, `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}` *does* work.

Comment: What distribution do you have (TeX Live, MiKTeX, MacTeX)? On what operating system are you running (Windows, Unix, Mac)?

Comment: TexShop is just the front-end/text editor. What we really need is the informations @Werner asked about. Normally you should be able to update packages using a package manager provided by you (La)TeX installation.

Comment: As you are using TexShop, you are probably on a Mac. Maybe the easiest solution for you would be to uninstall what you have, then download a recent version of [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/) and install it. MacTeX includes TexShop and TexWorks as editors and it also includes the tikz/pgf packages.

Comment: Your session seem to have expired and so you automatically got a new unregistered account. This stopped you from editing your question. I now merged your accounts together and moved your new information into the question. Please consider registering your account to avoid this in the future.

Comment: TeXLive-2007? This is way outdated! Try to install a modern MacTeX which is based on TeX Live 2011. This will include a modern version of PGF/TikZ.

Answer (score 4):

Your TeX distribution is so old that I could not say for sure that the current version of PGF/TikZ would work smoothly with it – even if you get it installed, eventually.

I **strongly recommend installing a recent TeX distribution**, which will include PGF V2.1 out of the box. For the Mac, [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex) is broadly seen as the best choice regarding completeness and user experience.

As all recent distributions based on TexLive, it also supports easy upgrading of packages via the [TexLive Manager](http://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html), for which a [graphical front end](http://code.google.com/p/mactlmgr/) is available as well. So if some day PGF V3.x will be released, it will be more easy to upgrade again.